# How do I enable/disable a button, using another button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to enable/disable some buttons, using another toggle button.

I'm trying to do it by adding a class 'active' to the buttons, and targeting only the buttons with the class.

Here is an example (That doesn't work):

```js
$('#on-off').on('click', () => {
    $('#test').addClass('active');
    $('#indication').text('Test is active');
  });
  
  $('#test .active').on('click', () => {
    $('#result').text('Test was clicked!');
  });
```

```html
<button id='on-off'>Toggle Test</button>
<div id='indication'></div>

<button id='test'>Test</button>
<div id='result'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The full code is [here](https://codepen.io/YogliB/pen/GyNLeY?editors=0011).

Comment: `targeting only the buttons with the class.` which class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the [`disabled` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) to enable or disable it. You can use `.prop()` method

Also note `#test .active` will not work as its descendant selector and button has no child element.

```js
$('#on-off').on('click', () => {
  $('#test').prop('disabled', !$('#test').prop('disabled'));
  $('#indication').text('Test is active');
});

$('#test').on('click', () => {
  $('#result').text('Test was clicked!');
});
```

```html
<button id='on-off'>Toggle Test</button>
<div id='indication'></div>

<button id='test'>Test</button>
<div id='result'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```